# Global variables causing an error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

While trying to declare a global variable in IE8, it throws the following error:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method
Script.js, line 2 character 5
```

Here's a stripped down version of code which would cause the same error.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    GlobalVar = {};
}
```

Does anybody know why IE8 and before would cause an error while simply declaring a global variable?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You're missing a closing `)` on the `.ready()`

Comment: @What is the real name of `GlobalVar`? Are you sure you haven't named it a reserved word such as `class`?

Answer (score 0):

does:

```
var GlobalVar;

$(document).ready(function () {
    GlobalVar = {};
});
```

work?

Answer (score 0):

**On document.ready global var gets initlaized to 10 . It is globally accessed inside any function inside that script..**

```
<script>

    var GlobalVar;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        GlobalVar = 10;
        temp();
    });

    function temp()
    {
      var a = GlobalVar;

      alert(a); //gives you that 10 


    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just add an issue that sound similar.

Make sure that the variable is not set from another script. You will then get a conflict between the previously initialized variable and your call "GlobalVar = {}".

Make sure that you GlobalVar is local to your jQuery ready call by adding var in front of it.
var GlobalVar = {};

Answer (score 0):

Implicit globals are a bad coding practice. You should do

```
window.GlobalVar
```

instead.